# Why can't I enable the 'new' button of action?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, add-on, actions

I want to import the action template of action editor, and use template ID to display it.
But the 'new' button is disabled, how could I active it?

here is my code currently:

```
import bpy

def drawRenderEngine(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        ob = context.object

        window = context.window
        screen = context.screen
        scene = window.scene

        if ob is not None:
            bpy.context.object.animation_data_create()
            layout.template_ID(context.object.animation_data, "action", new='action.new')




bpy.types.TOPBAR_HT_upper_bar.draw_right = drawRenderEngine
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The operator does not poll.**

The issue arises since the operator `bpy.ops.action.new` does not poll in the toolbar header.

Similarly in python console

```
>>> bpy.ops.action.new.poll()
False
```

Closer inspection of the action editor UI code, will see that the template object is the dope sheet space `st = context.space_data` not the animation data of the context object. My guess is the operator uses space to poll.

Code wise will confess to never using this operator; to add a new action would instead

```
action = bpy.data.actions.new(name)
```

and assign it to the animation data of the object I'm animating.

Enough waffle. Recommend here creating an operator `bpy.ops.foo.bar`  that makes the new action and assigns it where you wish, it appears from Q this is on the active object  Call the following from your operators execute method.

```
def main(context):
    ob = context.object
    name = f"{ob.name}Action"
    action = bpy.data.actions.new(name)
    # choose whether to set as active action or whatever
    ob.animation_data_create()
    ob.animation_data.action = action
```

Have it poll if there is a context object

Then use it instead for new

```
layout.template_ID(ob.animation_data, "action", new="foo.bar")
```

Side Note.

The draw method is only meant for drawing to the UI. If you put an `__init__` in a panel class will see they are initialized constantly.

Trying to alter objects in any way during a draw will result in an error.  This applies to

```
bpy.context.object.animation_data_create()
```

in question code.